# Python write web scrape data to csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am still extremely new to Python, and I am working on an assignment for my school.

I need to write code to pull all of the html from a website then save it to a `csv` file.

I believe I somehow need to turn the links into a list and then write the list, but I'm unsure how to do that.

This is what I have so far:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import csv

search_link = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r = requests.get(search_link)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
all_links = soup.find_all("a")

rem_dup = set()
for link in all_links:
    hrefs = str(link.get("href"))
    if hrefs.startswith('#http'):
        rem_dup.add(hrefs[1:])
    elif hrefs.endswith('.gov'):
        rem_dup.add(hrefs + '/')
    elif hrefs.startswith('/'):
        rem_dup.add('https://www.census.gov' + hrefs)
    else:
        rem_dup.add(hrefs)

filename = "Page_Links.csv"
f = open(filename, "w+")
f.write("LINKS\n")
f.write(all_links)
f.close()
```

Comment: Do you have errors? What do you get?

Comment: Yes I get an error: 
    File "python_class.py", line 27, in <module> f.write(all_links)
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not ResultSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `write()` function expects a character buffer object as a parameter. `all_links` essentially holds the ResultSet of all the hyperlinks. So, instead of -

```
f.write(all_links)
```

You should be writing the values in the `set()` defined by the `rem_dup` variable (since those contain the actual hyperlinks represented in a string format) -

```
for hyperlink in rem_dup:
    f.write(hyperlink + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`all_links` is a set or results from Beautiful Soup. `rem_dup` is where you are storing all of the hrefs, so I assume that's what you want to be writing to the file, so just `f.write(rem_dup)`.

Further explanation: `rem_dup` is actually a set. If you want it to be a list, then say `rem_dup = list()` instead of `set()`. `append` is usually used with lists, so you are using the correct syntax/.